# Getting Error while running Kafka command Kafka-topic.bat

Tags: apache-kafka

While Running the Kafak command getting the below error

> kafka-topic.bat

\IBM\WebSphere was unexpected at this time.

**User Variables**

Path= C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\KRISHNA\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\KRISHNA\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin

**System Variables**

Path= C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib64;C:\app\KRISHNA\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\app\KRISHNA\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\tibco\tibrv\8.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin;C:\FirFoxDriver;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\gradle\gradle-4.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin

**Classpath=**  C:\tibco\tibrv\8.3\lib\tibrvnative.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mq.jar

Comment: Hi, can you share your PATH and CLASSPATH ?

Comment: ^ Neither of those can contain spaces

Comment: Hi Yannick, I have added classpath and Path above along with Question